# function returns void even if i set the return statement to array?

Tags: typescript

I am working on this function that takes an array of distance meters is the default, and converts is back to feet and miles, the problems is I am getting this error I stated that option must return an array of numbers any idea where is this syntax error.
Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.

```js
const option = () => {
    let arr = [200, 400, 800, 1000, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    
      return arr.map((x, i) => {
        i <= 3 ? x * 3.281 : x / 1.609;
      });
   }
    
    
  console.log(option());
```

Comment: You miss return inside the map function ```return i <= 3 ? x * 3.281 : x / 1.609;```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are both missing a `return` and not: when using an arrow function, if your function body is a single statement, you can omit both the `{}` *and* the `return` statement:

```js
const option = () => {
    let arr = [200, 400, 800, 1000, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    
      return arr.map((x, i) => i <= 3 ? x * 3.281 : x / 1.609);
   }
    
    
  console.log(option());
```

Incidentally, this also lets you do things like:

```js
const materials = [
  'Hydrogen',
  'Helium',
  'Lithium',
  'Beryllium'
];

console.log(materials.map(material => material.length));
```

[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: so I confused the short hand with the longhand :D

Comment: @Richardson Exactly! You must omit _both_ the braces _and_ the `return`, but only if the function body is a single statement. I love this syntax, personally.

Answer (score 1):

There's missing a return statement inside the arrow function passed to map

```js
return arr.map((x, i) => {
    return i <= 3 ? x * 3.281 : x / 1.609;
});
```

to return a value without writing *return*, you can do like this

```js
return arr.map((x, i) => (
    i <= 3 ? x * 3.281 : x / 1.609;
));
```

replace `{` with `(`

Comment: shouldn't the map return by default ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to return the value once it is passes through the map.

```
const option = (): number[] => {
        let arr = [200, 400, 800, 1000, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        
         arr = arr.map((x, i) => {
            return i <= 3 ? x * 3.281 : x / 1.609;
          });
          return arr;
        }
```

Comment: This won't work. Either you need to make `arr` is `let` and assign map result to it or return the map result directly.

Comment: you're right, i did miss making it a let